# VHDL indexing with Variables or Signals?

Tags: variables, signals, vhdl, fpga

I've seen both methods but was wondering the pros and cons for indexing an array with a signal vs a variable

I understand that the variable updates immediately and is local to the process and the signal is dependent upon the clock cycle and is seen by all processes but, is there anything beyond that which should be considered during synthesis?

Here's an example as to what I mean by indexing and we can assume for this specific scenario that the index is NOT needed outside of this process.

```
process (clk)
variable index_counter : integer range 0 to 8 := 0;
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      storage_unit(index_counter) <= input_pin;
      index_counter := index_counter + 1;

      ......
      ** [ additional logic for resetting a counter ] **
      ......

   end if;
end process
```

I have also seen this approach taken where there is a signal declared for the index counter...

```
process (clk)
begin
   if rising_edge(clk) then
      storage_unit(index_counter) <= input_pin;
      input_pin <= input_pin + 1;

      ......
      ** [ additional logic for resetting a counter ] **
      ......
   end if;
end process;
```

Obviously very similar approaches but what is the difference between the two approaches? Is one preferred over another? If so, why?

Thank you!

Comment: In terms of synthesis, they should both produce the same result - a registered read address. In my view, the signal is prefered bacause code order makes no difference to synthesis result, so inadvertantly moving the add assignment above the storage lookup wont affect the circuit produced. It also may get you known as the "wacky variable guy", depending on the engineers you work with.

Comment: Thank you! That is good to know. I was searching other's UART modules and some had counters for the bit periods as variables and others had them as signals.. I was not sure really the difference.

Comment: What is the increment supposed to do when you get to 8 and then want to add 1 to it?   Your code needs to include this.   The range constraint only says, if a value outside of this range is assigned to index_counter, then it is an error.

Comment: Thank you @JimLewis for the response, I did not add any additional logic but just put it as a comment for "resetting the counter" ... the main concern was just regarding the indexing part in the first few lines of the code within the process.. Thanks and sorry for any confusion